# Comparing JSON Data to MySQL Table, Updating Rows and Inserting New Rows

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron

I'm trying to wrap my head around a problem and would appreciate some advice.

I've built a PHP script that pulls a large amount of JSON data from a URL. It then runs through that data and inputs it in to a MySQL database.
I want to use a Cron job that pulls the JSON data every 2 or 3 hours, and if anything has changed compared to the data in the MySQL table, it updates it. If there are new records, it adds those.

The old system a friend was using would basically pull all of the data every 2/3 hours and overwrite the old data. This is fine for small amounts of data, but it seems super impractical to be writing 10,000-20,000 rows to a table every 2/3 hours.

Each JSON object has a unique identifier - so I was thinking of doing something like:

1. Pull MySQL table data in to an array;
2. Pull JSON data in to an array.
3. Use the unique identifier for each entry in the JSON data to search against the MySQL data. If entries are not the same, update MySQL table. If entry doesn't exist, insert a new row.

I'm looking for some tips on the best way / most efficient and fastest way to do this. I've been told I'm super bad at explaining things so let me know if I need to add any more detail.